# Excel VBA Match function not working

Tags: vba

I'm using INDEX and MATCH functions to pull data which is concatenated string of G2 and H2 from column D (sorry I don't have enough points to attach pic). Column D has INDEX(column A and column B) and columns A and B have values till 12th row. MATCH is working fine giving me the position as 6 on the worksheet. But when I use this in VBA code as shown below,INDEX is working in the VBA code (can be seen through MsgBox) but MATCH function which would allot value to the variable 'check' isn't working. I have been breaking my head for really long. Need help from experts here. Somebody please tell me where am I going wrong?

```
Sub testindex()

Dim check As Long

Set sh = Sheets("Sheet1")

For j = 1 To 11

'Index value is correctly shown
MsgBox "Index Value=" & Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(sh.Range("A2:B12"), j, 1) & Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(sh.Range("A2:B12"), j, 2)

'Cells(7, 4)=ISA737775 same as G2&H2
MsgBox "Cells(7,4)=" & Cells(7, 4)
check = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(Cells(7, 4), Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(sh.Range("A2:B12"), j, 1) & Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(sh.Range("A2:B12"), j, 2), 0)

Next j

End Sub
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Match expects the second paramater to be in the form of a range. When you call match through VBA that range actually needs to be a range object, not just some string like "A1:A12" or whatever it is that your concatenated Index formulas output.

At any rate, you are iterating already, so why not just call those values directly instead of pulling their values through Index?

`check = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(Cells(7, 4), sh.Range("A" & 2 + j).value & sh.Range("B" & 2 + j), 0)`

Which is writing the same exact thing but without having to use a taxing INDEX function in VBA to do it. Note that this still won't work because the second parameter of match is still just a string which is a concatenated value from Column A and Column B. You could convert to a range by sticking them in the range object with:

`check = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(Cells(7, 4), sh.Range(sh.Range("A" & 2 + j).value & sh.Range("B" & 2 + j)), 0)`

I'm assuming that the values in A and B are actual cell names that when concatenated will make a range. Like when `j=1` then the it would be like check=Match(Cells(7,4), sh.Range("G2:H50"), 0) or something...